# cloud scheduler does not start for an hour on 'Daylight Saving Time Ended' event, when US rolls back clocks for 1 hour

Tags: scheduler

So, we have an issue that we have some active schedulers that run every 4mins or so. And they get stuck for an hour or even more when US rolls back clocks for 1 hour. This happened a 3rd year in a row. There is no code that i need to provide. Running manually returned success.
Frequency: */4 * * * * (America/Los_Angeles)

Comment: What is the environment? Which cron daemon and which version of it is used?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a wrong place to post an issue, since it's an issue with cloud service provider (at least we believe so). We use node environment, but everything regarding cron jobs is on cloud side.